# SQL Query group by Postcode multiple Sums

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data:

| ID | Weight | Postcode | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 56222 | 2022 |
| 2 | 24 | 56332 | 2022 |
| 3 | 50 | 56442 | 2022 |
| 4 | 22 | 62331 | 2022 |
| 5 | 80 | 72130 | 2022 |

and i want to query it that i get the data like this:
Grouped by Postcode and splitted in different weight ranges.
and then just Count of the amount of entrys.

| Postcode/Weight | 0-20 | 21-40 | 41-60 | 61-80 | 81-100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 62 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 72 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Is there any way to query this in SQL?

Comment: Use conditional aggregation or `PIVOT`; a search of these will give you a wealth of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    p.postcode, 
    COUNT(p20.id) as "0-20",
    COUNT(p40.id) as "21-40",
    COUNT(p60.id) as "41-60",
    COUNT(p80.id) as "61-80",
    COUNT(p100.id) as "81-100"
FROM packs p 
    LEFT JOIN packs p20 ON p20.postcode=p.postcode AND p20.weight < 20  
    LEFT JOIN packs p40 ON p40.postcode=p.postcode AND p40.weight >= 21 AND p40.weight <= 40 
    LEFT JOIN packs p60 ON p60.postcode=p.postcode AND p60.weight >= 41 AND p60.weight <= 60
    LEFT JOIN packs p80 ON p80.postcode=p.postcode AND p80.weight >= 61 AND p80.weight <= 80
    LEFT JOIN packs p100 ON p100.postcode=p.postcode AND p100.weight >= 81 AND p100.weight <= 100 
GROUP by postcode;
```

Result:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCsnF.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).